# Power automate nested switch does not display option of adding new actions under 5th level switch

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, limitations

I have a workflow where I have multi level (7-8) of approvals with one by one level at one point of time.

In one branch [Case 1] of root level switch I am able to nest up to 6 more switch statement one underneath another, but when I am going to next branch [Case 2] of root level switch, it is not displaying me option of adding more action within it under the hood of 4th level switch case.

RootSwitch => case1>Level2 Switch case1>Level3 Switch case1>Level4 Switch case1>Level5 Switch case1>Level6 Switch case1> ------- Works fine, but below is not displaying option to add more actions

RootSwitch => case2>Level2 Switch case1>Level3 Switch case1>Level4 Switch case1>Level5 Switch case1> Here I don't see "Add Actions" option under the Case branches.

I noticed under "RootSwitch => case2>Level2 Switch case1>Level3 Switch case1>Level4 Switch case1>" if I add switch/condition/apply to each action it does not allow me to add actions within them.

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

In Power Automate, **Switch scope cases limit** is 25.

**Source**: [Flow definition limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config)

I think this is not allowing you to add more cases.

You should check for some workarounds like: [Switch and Case limits](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Switch-and-Case-limits/td-p/542551)

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my case each switch action has 3-5 cases in it and the 'add actions' option does not show even if I do add 'apply to each' action at 4th level instead of an switch.

Comment: Do you have nested switch cases?

Comment: Yes, have multiple switch case nested as below.

RootSwitch => case1>Level2 Switch case1>Level3 Switch case1>Level4 Switch case1>Level5 Switch case1>Level6 Switch case1> ------- Works fine, but below is not displaying option to add more actions

RootSwitch => case2>Level2 Switch case1>Level3 Switch case1>Level4 Switch case1>Level5 Switch case1> Here I don't see "Add Actions" option under the Case branches.